# Macro want to use symbol instead of string in clojure

Tags: macros, clojure, lisp

So trying to make something like the haskell lambda syntax, and with a macro this is what I've got:

```
(defmacro / [& all]
  (let [args (take-while #(not (= %1 "=>")) all)
        argCount (count args)
        expr (last (split-at (+ argCount 1) all))]
    `(fn ~(vec args) (~@expr))))

(reduce (/ x y "=>" + x y) [1 2 3])
```

This works well enough, but the last thing I'd like to do is make it so I don't need the `"=>"` but can just use `=>`

Any tips how I might make `=>` a valid symbol that I can just parse in the context as I'm referring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the `name` of the symbol against the string:

```
(defmacro / [& all]
  (let [args (take-while #(not (= (name %1) "=>")) all)
        argCount (count args)
        expr (last (split-at (+ argCount 1) all))]
    `(fn ~(vec args) (~@expr))))
```

Comment: Yes! This even let me use -> instead of =>! Lovely! Thanks!